# What happens when you rsync without a destination?

Tags: linux, rsync, file-copy

To make the story short, I did an rsync:

`rsync -avP user@exampleserver.com:/tmp/`

And I forgot to put in my source directory...

I really meant to run:

`rsync -avP /tmp/ user@exampleserver.com:/tmp/`

It printed a bunch of files, but I don't know where it copied them because I didn't specify a destination.  Does anyone know what happened?  I did an `ls` on the current folder, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: I'd assume you'd just de-rez.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

From `man rsync`:

```
   Usages with just one SRC arg and no DEST arg will list the source files
   instead of copying.
```

this as explanation below the invocation options, for you the invocation matches:

```
Pull: rsync [OPTION...] [USER@]HOST::SRC... [DEST]
```

Comment: That's a relief but why not just print an error

Comment: @0A0D actually it is a **feature** that I have used. You first run without a destination to see what file are going to involved and make sure those are the right ones, and then you reissue the command with the destination appended.

Comment: @Anthon: Ah, that would make sense. I suppose a -t (for test) would be more verbose to me.

Comment: @0A0D Dry run of rsync is invoked with -n/--dry-run.

Comment: @Brian -t is not for testing. It has a completely different meaning... DO NOT use it for testing... As said you can use -n if you want to test... -t is something else

Comment: @inemanja: it was more commentary on the -t option than anything else

Comment: @Brian I assumed you new. It was more of message to someone who tumble into comments, not to use - t for testing..